# Unexpected behaviour with a pure virtual function overridden in a derived type

Tags: c++, templates, inheritance, virtual, overriding

This is one of those cases where I thought I understood C++ virtual methods reasonably well, and then an example comes along where I realise that, sadly, I don't. Is there anyone reading this who can make sense of the following?

Here is some test code in which I define a very simple base class (actually just a two-element struct), an abstract template class containing a virtual void method, and then a derived class which inherits from both of them and explictly overrides the virtual void method with a concrete method.

```
#include <string.h>  // For memcpy
#include <vector>    // For std::vector

struct int_array_C
{
    int  n;
    int* contents;
};

template <typename T> class array_template
{
public:
    array_template<T>() {}

    array_template<T>(const array_template<T> &source) 
    {
        *p_n = *(source.p_n);
        setPointers(&(source.local_contents[0]));
    }

    // ..and in reality, a bunch of other array manipulation functions

protected:
    virtual void setPointers(const T* data) = 0;

    int *p_n;
    std::vector<T> local_contents;
};

class int_array : public int_array_C, public array_template<int> 
{
public:
    int_array() : array_template<int>() 
    { 
        n = 0; contents = NULL; 
    }

protected:
    virtual void setPointers(const int* data)
    {
        p_n = &n;
        local_contents.resize(n);
        memcpy(static_cast<void *>(&local_contents[0]), 
               static_cast<const void *>(data), n*sizeof(int));
        contents = &local_contents[0];
    }
};

int main()
{
    int_array myArray;
    int_array yourArray(myArray);
    return 1;
}
```

When the copy constructor is called in the second line of main(), the argument is an instance of the derived class which has a concrete setPointers() method. Therefore, when the template class's copy constructor is called and the call to setPointers() is encountered, I'd expect the rules of polymorphism to kick in and the *derived* class's setPointers() method to be called.

In fact, however, the compiler chokes on this; at compilation time I get a warning saying

```
"Warning: call of pure virtual function at line 18"
```

and at link time the linker fails with a message saying

```
error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "protected: virtual void __cdecl array_template<int>::setPointers(int const *)" (?setPointers@?$array_template@H@@MEAAXPEBH@Z) referenced in function "public: __cdecl array_template<int>::array_template<int>(class array_template<int> const &)" (??0?$array_template@H@@QEAA@AEBV0@@Z)
```

Exactly the same thing happens (with slight variation in the text of the error messages) using Visual C++ and Intel C++ on Windows and gcc on Linux, so it's obviously a genuine violation of language rules rather than just being a compiler quirk. Yet I can't see what the problem is.

So, what am I doing wrong and how might I make this work as intended?

Comment: The code has a lot of errors dude.

Comment: You can't call a derived class's virtual function from a base class constructor, because at the time it's called the derived class hasn't been constructed yet.

Comment: the call is wrong, but i still don't understand why this ends up as a linking error rather than runtime UB

Comment: I disagree with the assertion that this is a duplicate of the cited answer. There are indeed many things that can cause an undefined reference error at link time, but I can't find this one amongst those listed there. As discussed below (and nailed by @Paul Griffiths), the key to this problem is the order in which the base class methods and the derived class methods are instantiated, and I can't find anything about that in the cited answer. The FAQ referenced by Cheers and hth. Alf is much more relevant, but I don't think I'd even have found the answer there without Paul Griffiths' comment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Paul Griffiths nailed it with his comment under my original question:

"You can't call a derived class's virtual function from a base class constructor, because at the time it's called the derived class hasn't been constructed yet."

That's the critical thing: the call occurs in the constructor, and because the base class's constructor is called before the derived class exists, there *is* no concrete version of setPointers to call yet (at least, not in the new object that is in the process of being created; the fact that the old object being passed as an argument has one is irrelevant here).

The solution is pretty simple: move the copy constructor out of the template altogether and place it within the derived class instead. It's only a two-line function so it's not too painful to do this with each of my dozen or so derived classes, and it solves the problem.

[N.B. If anyone is wondering what all this is in aid of, this is part of a large mixed-language application. I want to have a set of container functions which have the functionality of a std::vector when used in C++, so that I can resize, reference, copy etc. at will, but then pass to a plain C subroutine expecting just the base struct. Everything except the template copy constructor has been working well for a long time now!]

Comment: Note that the default constructor (in the current code) leaves member `p_n` with an indeterminate pointer value.

Comment: Thank you, well spotted.

Answer (score 0):

In the execution of a constructor body for a class `T` the dynamic type is `T`. Any direct or indirect call of a pure virtual `T` member function here, is therefore invalid. It's some extra type checking security of C++, ensuring that you don't accidentally get into derived class code before the derived class sub-object has been properly initialized (or at least given the chance).

However, I don't understand why it ends up as a linking error.

Regarding solutions, this is [a FAQ](http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq/calling-virtuals-from-ctor-idiom.html); essentially you have to somehow pass the derived class functionality or data up to the base class, and there are many ways to do that. As it happens I once convinced Marshall to include that FAQ item. So I can to some degree claim it as my answer to your problem. :-)

---

*Update* on the original code behavior.

Adding the following:

```
template< class T >
void array_template<T>::setPointers( const T* data )
{
    using namespace std;
    clog << "!pure virtual setPointers called!" << endl;
}
```

it turned out that with both Visual C++ 12.0 and g++ 4.8.2 it was called.

The call is Undefined Behavior so both compilers are in their right to produce such behavior, but still it surprised me. I'd think instead they would put a pointer to some error function in the vtable. Anyway, it explains the linking errors, with these two compilers.

Comment: The linker error is explained a bit more in [this SO answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11437242/linker-error-on-pure-virtual-function-call-with-gcc). A pure virtual method can be defined as explained [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2089083/pure-virtual-function-with-implementation) but I too wouldn't expect it to be called in this situation either.

Comment: @uesp: Well the question of why both compilers emit a call to an implementation in the call's class is what's baffling, and is  not answered by David. The call is UB and trivially so, so they *can* do that. It's the impracticality of it and that they both do it, that baffles me; I don't understand it, but I feel that there is something to understand.

Comment: Why wouldn't it be OK if the function was defined in another translation unit?

Comment: @PaulGriffiths: Even if the class is a template the relevant specialization of it can be defined in another translation unit, there's no problem there. The problem is simply that a virtual call of a class T pure virtual function, when the dynamic type is T, is UB no matter whether the function is defined or not. And a practical way to handle that is to place an error-generating stub in the T vtable. The linking error is nice but as shown it can't be relied on, so it's less practical, just baffling.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot call `virtual` methods from base class constructors and get derived class methods: those are set up after the base class is constructed.

Try changing the layout of your inheritsnce:

```
class int_array_impl:public int_array_C{...};
template<class T,class B>class array_template:public B{
  //...
};
typedef array_template<int, int_array_impl> int_array;
```

make the method non-virtual, get rid of pure virtual stuff in array_template, and just blindlh invoke `this->method`.  If `B` has it, it will be called.

Either forward constructors, or have a 4th class under `array_template` that provides custom ones.

Comment: Thank you, I would have accepted this as the answer had Paul Griffiths not got in with his comment first.