# Linker C++11 error with header-only

Tags: c++, c++11, linker, clang

I have tried to program a header-only library for an existing project.
The compiler has no error (anymore), but the linker (clang) failed...

I am using CMake and my library is added with the following lines:

```
set(RODE_DIR rode)
include_directories (${RODE_DIR})
```

The error is the following:

```
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "sfm::StreamlineWrf::ComputeStreamline(sfm::NdArray<float>*, sfm::NdArray<float>*, sfm::NdArray<float>*, sfm::NdArray<float>*, int&, int&, int&, double const*, int, double, std::__1::vector<double, std::__1::allocator<double> >*)", referenced from:
      _main in wrf2sl.cc.o
  "sfm::ijktos(sfm::NdArray<float>*, sfm::NdArray<float>*, sfm::NdArray<float>*, int const*, double const*, double*, double*, double*)", referenced from:
      _main in wrf2sl.cc.o
  "typeinfo for MethodModel", referenced from:
      typeinfo for HeunEuler1 in wrf2sl.cc.o
      typeinfo for HeunEuler2 in wrf2sl.cc.o
      typeinfo for DormandPrince in wrf2sl.cc.o
      typeinfo for BogackiShampine in wrf2sl.cc.o
      typeinfo for RK41 in wrf2sl.cc.o
  "vtable for MethodModel", referenced from:
      MethodModel::MethodModel() in wrf2sl.cc.o
      MethodModel::~MethodModel() in wrf2sl.cc.o
  NOTE: a missing vtable usually means the first non-inline virtual member function has no definition.
  "vtable for rODE", referenced from:
      rODE::rODE(std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> >, std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> >, std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> >, float) in wrf2sl.cc.o
  NOTE: a missing vtable usually means the first non-inline virtual member function has no definition.
  "vtable for Method", referenced from:
      Method::Method(std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> >, std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> >, std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> >, float) in wrf2sl.cc.o
  NOTE: a missing vtable usually means the first non-inline virtual member function has no definition.
  "vtable for Solver", referenced from:
      Solver::Solver(std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> >, std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> >, std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> >, float) in wrf2sl.cc.o
  NOTE: a missing vtable usually means the first non-inline virtual member function has no definition.
  "vtable for sfm::StreamlineWrf", referenced from:
      sfm::StreamlineWrf::StreamlineWrf(std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> >, std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> >, std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> >, float) in wrf2sl.cc.o
  NOTE: a missing vtable usually means the first non-inline virtual member function has no definition.
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
make[2]: *** [expt/wrf2sl] Error 1
make[1]: *** [expt/CMakeFiles/wrf2sl.dir/all] Error 2
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

Do you know what is going on?

Comment: I never heard of a library called rode, but it does not seem to be header only.

Comment: A header-only library _by definition_ defines all its symbols in its header.

Comment: This is the one I have done. So maybe I have made a mistake but basically I have just used headers for it. A bit like many libraries from Boost

Comment: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: every symbols from rODE are inside headers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The explanation is probably in the error:

"a missing vtable usually means the first non-inline virtual member function has no definition.
  "vtable for rODE", referenced from:"

Go through your classes , Method, MethodModel, Solver, etc, and check each of their virtual member functions, and make sure each has a definition which is in a .c / .cxx / .c++ module that is being linked. Probably you'll find one that either doesn't have a definition, or is defined in a file that isn't being linked by CMake.

Comment: Yes it was almost there. Actually the answer is there: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11437242/linker-error-on-pure-virtual-function-call-with-gcc, Thanks for your advice